# MySql time data type comparison with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, time, comparison

**I have a below situation where its throwing error.**

```
$time_to1=date("H:i:s", strtotime($endtime) - 3600);
$time_to2=date("H:i:s", strtotime($endtime) + 3600);


  $sql="select b.fullname, b.email,  a.needpooling, a.start_location,
a.end_location,a.start_time||' '||s_time as start_time,a.end_time||' '||e_time as end_time
          from User_planned_tour a, user_accounts b
     where a.username=b.username 
       and UPPER(a.start_location) like '%".$source."%' 
       and UPPER(a.end_location) like '%".$end."%' 
       and a.Start_time ='$begintime' 
       and a.End_time='$endtime1'
       **and a.s_time between '".$time_from1."' and '".$time_from2."'   
       and a.e_time between '".$time_to1."' and '".$time_to2."'**
       and b.id in(select fid from jcow_friends where uid ='".$id."')
      order by a.start_location,a.end_location,a.Start_time, a.End_time, b.username ,a.NeedPooling";
```

Comment: And what error is it throwing?

Comment: What if `$endtime` has time like `00:15`? Then your `$time_to1` will be `23:15` and `$time_to2` will be `01:15`, so BETWEEN this 2 times, no results will ever be returned.

Comment: I am very bad in mysql but if I am understanding you properly then I need add the date part also along with the time during comparison or do I have any other way to do this?